Bounded differentiation operator on compact intervals with $L^2$ norm
It is known that the differentiation operator $D$ is not bounded on $C^1([0,1])$ with $L^2$ norm (counterexample: $f(x)=x^n$). Now I am wondering whether there is an infinitely dimensional subspace such that $D$ is indeed bounded on it? For example,
$$
X=\{f\in C^{\infty}([0,1])\vert\sup_{n\ge0}\Vert f^{(n)}\Vert_{\infty}<\infty\}
$$
(I do not know whether it is true and cannot give a proof). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

To be clear, you want an infinite-dimensional (closed?) subspace of $L^2([0, 1])$, on which the differentiation is bounded in the $L^2$-norm?

@Aleksei Kulikov Yes, an infinite-dimensional subspace of $L^2([0,1])$ with as few restrictions as possible, but not necessarily closed.

A negative result, somehow related : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376087/banach-algebra-of-smooth-functions

I think the answer is no, there is no such infinite-dimensional subspace. Say, we have such a subspace $X$. I will assume that $X$ lies in the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}([0, 1])$, because otherwise it is not even clear what is $Df$, and what is its $L^2$-norm.
The key idea is that the eigenvalues of $D$ on $W^{1, 2}([0, 1])$ tend to infinity (they are $\lambda_n = \pi (n-1)$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, up to the unimodular factos, if I didn't make any arithmetic mistakes), and therefore by the min-max principle in any $n$-dimensional subspace we can find a vector $f$ for which $||Df||\ge |\lambda_n| ||f||$.
Hence, if our space in infinite-dimensional, we can find such an $f_n$ for any $n$, and since $|\lambda_n| \to \infty$, the derivative operator is not bounded (by bounded I of course here mean that there exists a universal $C > 0$ such that $||Df|| \le C ||f||$).

I think technically I should talk about singular values, or eigenvalues of $-D^2$, but the idea still stands.

An easier but simialr approach: on this subspace $X$, the $L^2$ and $H^1$ norms are equivalent. Since the embedding of $H^1 \to L^2$ is compact, the unit ball of $X$ is compact.

@GiorgioMetafune this requires explaining why we can assume that $X$ is complete (which is not hard, but still requires a couple of words). Very nice argument regardless!

I think the problem with this argument is that $iD$ with domain $H^1$ not self-adjoint of $L^2(0,1)$, and we have a one-parameter family $T_{\alpha}$ of self-adjoint restrictions (corresponding to boundary conditions). Your argument would apply to a single $T_{\alpha}$, but it could be that an infinite-dimensional subspace intersects all of the $D(T_{\alpha})$.

@ChristianRemling by sacrificing two extra dimensions we can assume zero boundary conditions, say. However, the eigenvalues I wrote are (I think) for the Neumann boundary conditions, which, if I was taught right, are the biggest ones and hold for the whole $W^{1, 2}(0, 1)$.

@AlekseiKulikov I do not see any hidden completeness assumption in the argument. Assume that $D$ is bounded on $X \subset H^1$, with $X$ just a subspace. Then the $L^2$ and $H^1$ norm are equivalent on $X$ by assumption. If I take $(f_n)$ in the unit ball of $X$ then it has a convergent subsequence in $L^2$. However, if $dim X=\infty$ i can select $(f_n)$ such that $|f_n-f_m|_2 \geq 1/2$ by the Riesz lemma. Neverthless I agree that $D$ would be also bounded  on the $L^2$ closure of $X$.

@AlekseiKulikov: The deficiency index is $1$, so there are no Neumann conditions here. The self-adjoint boundary conditions are $f(1)=e^{i\alpha}f(0)$. But I guess this technical detail is irrelevant. My comment was essentially: What about something like the $X$ from my answer or $X =$ span of $e^{i\lambda t}$, $0\le\lambda\le 1$. I don't think it's clear (not to me at least) that this $X$ intersects $D(T_{\alpha})$ in an infinite-dimensional space for any fixed $\alpha$, but your argument seems to be based on this.

Or, to say this in still another way: The space of lowest eigenfunctions for all self-adjoint realizations is already infinite-dimensional, so the fact that you run out of these for a fixed realization (because of discrete spectrum) does not stop $X$ from being built from low eigenfunctions only.

@ChristianRemling well, it is not literally the same as written in my answer (although in spirit it is the same), but we can alternatively do the following: pick a function $f\in X$ with $f(\frac{k}{n}) = 0$ by basic linear algebra, then use Poincaré--Wirtinger inequality on each interval $(\frac{k}{n}, \frac{k+1}{n})$.
